# How to implement implicit type casting into a statically typed language

Tags: types, compiler-construction, implicit-conversion

I've been attempting to implement implicit type casting into my language which makes use of type inference. I have all the mechanisms in place for determining type conversions and valid combinations, however I realised my implementation was flawed and naive.

During my semantic analysis phase I'd determine the types involved like so:

```
x = 2 // INT
y = x + 1.3123 // ADD(INT & FLOAT) ❌
```

Then I'd wrap the actual AST node containing the incompatible type with another method call node like so:

```
x = 2 // INT
y = float(x) + 1.3123 // ADD(FLOAT & FLOAT) ✔️
```

From there the code generator would simply run the function `float(x)` and successfully add together the two floats.

However I realised this system was flawed for methods, since wrapping a node with a method call did not allow for more complex operations such as:

```
func testfunction(x, y):
    return x + y // return x + float(y) ❌ return x + y ❌

testfunction(1.2, 2)
testfunction("test", "test2")
```

In this situation it is not possible to add the appropriate cast to y in the case of the first call, since a explicit cast to a float would not allow for the second call to take place (float + string).

How do statically typed languages mark code to be implicitly casted, especially in cases where it might be called again with different types? Details of implementation would be very appreciated, especially in regards to semantic analysis, code generations and ASTs.

**Edit**:

On request here's some information about my current type system.

My binary operator implementation several overloads e.g. ADD(INT, INT), ADD(FLOAT, FLOAT). The selected overload is bound with a return type and also a pointer to a C++ method that will perform the actual operation in the code generation phase.
The overload is selected that has the least non negative conversion cost for the inputted types e.g. passing ADD(INT, FLOAT)

```
ADD(INT, INT) // cost -1 (can't convert float to int)
ADD(FLOAT, FLOAT) // cost 1 (float to int)
```

The correct overload is picked during semantic analysis and bound to the AST node for use in the code generator. This is similar to my method system, e.g. float(INT), float(FLOAT)

Comment: Most statically typed languages with global type inference don't allow implicit conversions at all. Anyway, can you explain a bit what your type system looks like and what the inferred type of your `add` function would be in your type system when we don't take type conversions into account?

Comment: To clarify your edit: Are you saying that `testfunction` (née `add`) wouldn't be inferred to have one specific type, but instead create an overload for each possible combination of parameter types for which the body type checks? If so, I think you can handle implicit conversions by letting each such overload have its own body where you insert the appropriate conversions. That said, I'm not sure how well this approach works in practice. You'll end up with a lot of overloads and I don't know how you're going to handle user-defined types that might not be visible when the function is defined.

Comment: For comparison: In the languages I know with global type inference, `testfunction` would have a single inferred type that's either generic (like `Num a => a -> a -> a` in Haskell or `^a -> ^b -> ^c when (^a or ^b) : (static member (+) : ^a * ^b -> ^c)` (read: "this function can take any types `^a` and `^b`, such that a plus operator exists for those types and the return type will be that of that plus operator) in F# when the function is inline) or specific to one concrete type (i.e. `int -> int -> int` in SML, OCaml and F# when the function is not inline).

Comment: @sepp2k in the case of `testfunction` I'm not concerned with the parameters received, but what is done with it in the logic: i.e. return x + y. The issue stands that attempting to plus together a float and a int, with my system, would add a cast to y float(y) which means that the method is no longer reusable for the string + string, since y in that scenario will be forced to cast to a float

Comment: Essentially the issue is, how can I signal the code generator to cast y to float but not in a way that forces the function to be limited only to accept a value of y as float/int from then on. With the current system, once a float(y) is put in place, a string cannot be y any more

Comment: So do you generate one overload per possible type as I speculated or don't you? If you do, then you can just generate the `float` call for those overloads where it makes sense and that wouldn't affect the other overloads (though the caveats from my previous comment regarding user-defined types and such would still apply). If you don't, that brings us back to my initial question: what's the inferred type of `testfunction`?

Comment: @sepp2k Yes I do generate different overloads for possible types. So am I correct in saying that you suggest internalising the conversion into the overload body?